# How to multicast a file over a local network in Java

Tags: java, networking

I am able to sent files between a client and server using Sockets but I need to multicast files over a local network. Can someone please suggest an approach on how to go about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? You just have to open a `DatagramSocket`, read the file, and send the bits to the multicast address. The devil is in the detail: what are you going to do about dropped datagrams?

Comment: I haven't tried for multicast because I don't know how to reliably sent the file. I have read that Norm Protocol is one reliable solution in one of the stack overflow answers but I have no clue on how to go about it.Just to point out that I need to sent over a local network so what would be a good approach according to you if I want to sent it reliably?

Comment: Too broad. There are several reliable multicast protocols, and indeed if you can find JRMS to download from Oracle there is even an implementation of two of them in Java.